# Performance issue while changing font size

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-size, mousemove

I've put together this code and I'm having a problem grasping it. I want to make single text lines individually grow when you come closer to them with the cursor. The line that's the closes to be the largest and the ones further away to be smaller. I sort of works but it's not exactly the desired effect not mentioning the performance issue. It doesn't run smooth. Is there a way of optimizing the code?

```
(function() {

  jQuery(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    jQuery(".post__text__content").each( function() {
      $element  = jQuery(".post__text__content");
      mY = e.pageY;
      mX = e.pageX;
      distance = calculateDistance($element, mX, mY);
      fontsize = 80 - distance / 10 ;
      jQuery(this).css("font-size", fontsize)
    })
  });

  function calculateDistance(elem, mouseX, mouseY) {
    return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseX - (elem.offset().left+(elem.width()/2)), 2) + Math.pow(mouseY - (elem.offset().top+(elem.height()/2)), 2)));
  }

})();
```

Comment: Without HTML, bit hard to see how it's supposed to work, but doesn't look like it would work due to `$element = jQuery(".post__text__content");` - so all your calculations will be based on a single element.  Simply changing that line to `jQuery(this)` and it does *something* closer to what you describe: https://jsfiddle.net/5saycp6k/

Comment: To optimise it, find all the calculations/lookups that don't change, eg `elem.offset().left` `elem.width()` (depending on your HTML) and either store them as a single variable (if all the same) or as a lookup on the elem, `elem.data(width, elem.width())` which will(*should) be a quicker lookup than calculating

Comment: Another potential improvement (not tested) would be to use classes instead of `.css("font-size")` - it might not be as accurate, but with some transition effects would be substantially faster/smoother

Comment: I would also try to debounce your `fontsize` value. Just look for a debounce function somewhere.

Comment: I've made code pen https://codepen.io/tads_r/pen/OJpgKOX
Yes, there has to be jQuery(this) for it work.
I'll see with the transition on an added class. That sould speed it up since I believe CSS is faster than JS?

Comment: There's no speed issue on that codepen or the fiddle I did - the codepen works a bit strangely to me, probably because of the mouseX part of the calculation.  Maybe consider just the item under the mouse and within a certain Y range (eg 2 or 3 either side) and the others get the default height?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that classes are the way to go. Works smooth and has the desired effect.

I've changed it a bit and added classes to the main  element and the ones next to it.

```
(function() {
    
  jQuery(".post__text__content").hover(
    function () {
      jQuery(this).prev().addClass("sub_text");
      jQuery(this).addClass("main_text");
      jQuery(this).next().addClass("sub_text");
    },
    function () {
      jQuery(this).prev().removeClass("sub_text");
      jQuery(this).removeClass("main_text");
      jQuery(this).next().removeClass("sub_text");
    }
  );

})();
```

Here's a working pen:
https://codepen.io/tads_r/pen/WNpKRKw